# Enabling SSH on boot via config files

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

How can I configure ssh service to run on boot **other** than via shell? Is it through `/etc/init/ssh.conf` ? If that's the case, what parametters should I look for in it? 
The reason I can't do this through terminal is that I've lost SSH acces to the server. The hosting company enables a network recovery mode ssh acces, which in turn allows me to mount the partitions and access my server files. Their privacy policies do not allow them to acces the server file system or services. All they could was a server reboot which didn't solve the issue.

*note. OpenSSH is installed. Other services Apache/MySQL/php/proPTFd are running smoothly.*

Comment: paste the `ssh -vvv user@your-server-ip` using paste.ubuntu.com and if you can manually create a symbolic link of  `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` that might start the ssh service at boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to regain ssh access again. For some reason the ufw rule for port 22 was lost. It should have been the first place to look, but it was an error on my part to not question if ssh service was up. I made a bad assumption that it was down. Lesson learned.

If a beginner with the same issue stumbles on this, if you use ufw check your */lib/ufw/user.rules* and */lib/ufw/user6.rules* to see if a rule for OpenSSH exists. In my case adding the below solved it:

```
### tuple ### allow any 22 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```